# How to find out WHERE a PG error/warning/log happened?

Tags: postgresql, csv, logging

I have PostgreSQL CSV-log its "errors" according to this structure: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-CSVLOG

It doesn't include the file path to the script which ran the query, so I have no idea where it occurred besides the vague, essentially useless hint from the "application_name".

How do I make it log which file caused the error/warning/log?

My first thought was to just add my own column to the table, called `file_path`, but then I realized that this won't help, since my script which does the COPYing of the csvlog data into my table has no idea from where the entries origin, since they are not logged by PostgreSQL.

Without knowing where the error occurs, I might as well not have a log at all. How do I make it log the file path and not just the application_name? I'm baffled as to why this is lacking in the table structure/CSVlog dump format.

The "detail" column is almost always empty, so there are no file paths there for me to extract.

Comment: If you are running your script with `psql`, `psql` should generate error output indicating this.  That will go to psql's stderr, not to the server's log file.

Comment: jjanes: What do you mean by "running my script with psql"?

Comment: @Reef It looks like you have created two unregistered (cookie-based) accounts, which is why you couldn't comment on your 'own' question directly. If you use different devices or browsers, or otherwise clear cookies, you will need to register a permanent account to use this site effectively. https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/why-register

Answer (score 0):

The server has no idea what the name of the script file you are running on the client is, so it cannot report that information.

You need to log such problems on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make it log the file path and not just the application_name?

The piece of information you seem to be missing is that any script or more generally SQL session may change the contents of `application_name` anytime , with `SET` as an SQL command:

```
SET application_name TO 'Name of script with other details as needed';
```

So you actually have complete control over what's logged in that CSV field.